# All accumulation value of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

What would be all accumulation values of the following sequences and how would you calculate them? I'm  getting a bit lost.

$a_n := (\frac{3}{2})^{(-1)^nn}$

$d_n := (-3)^n + (1+(-1)^{3n})(2+\frac{(-1)^{4n}}{n^2})$

EDIT:

For the first one I tried to just take even or odd n and both converge to 0. But I feel like this is wrong. And for the second one I have no clue

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: For the first one I tried to just take even or odd n and both converge to 0. But I feel like this is wrong. And for the second one I have no clue

Comment: try to include the comment above as part of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Trying odd and even subsequence is a good move.

$$a_{2m}=(1.5)^{2m}\to \infty$$

$$a_{2m-1}=(1.5)^{-(2m-1)}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2m-1} \to 0$$

That is $0$ is an accumulation point for the sequence $a_n$.

$$d_{2m-1}=(-3)^{2m-1} \to -\infty$$
$$d_{2m}=3^{2m}+2\left( 2+\frac1{(2m)^2}\right)\to \infty$$

There is no accumulation point for $d_n$.

Comment: Alright, I get it. But how do you determine that you found ALL of them.

Comment: For the first question, one subsequence increases but the second subsequences decreases monotonically. no positive value can be approached infinetly many times. Similar reasoning for the second question, one gets arbitrarily large and one get arbitrarily negative, no finite number can be approached arbitrarily close infinitely many times.